# Tangential velocity - Spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

In a spherical coordinates system ($r$, $\theta$, $\phi$ ), assuming an angular rotation $\omega_z$ around the z-axis, the tangential velocity of a point can be expressed as:

$$V_x = -\omega_z R \sin\theta \sin\phi $$
$$ V_y = \omega_z R \sin\theta \cos\phi$$

What happens if I have a rotation $\omega_x$ around the $x$-axis? What are the equation for the $V_y$ and $V_z$ velocity components of the point?

Comment: Frankly, by far the easiest expressions come out when/if you redefine your coordinate azimuth and ascension angles to be defined  w.r.t.  x instead of z. In that case, you merely have (x,y,z)↦(y,z,x).

Answer (score 0):

The equation is always

$$ \boxed{\; \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r} \; } $$

where $\boldsymbol{\omega}  = \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z } $ and $\boldsymbol{r} = \pmatrix{ r \cos \phi \sin \theta \\ r \sin \phi \sin \theta \\ r \cos \theta} $

In your first case $\omega_z \neq 0$ while others are 0, and in the second case $\omega_x \neq 0$.

$$\boldsymbol{v} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & r\cos \theta & -r \sin \phi \sin \theta \\ -r \cos \theta & 0 & r \cos \phi \sin \theta \\ r \sin \phi \sin \theta & -r \cos \phi \sin \theta & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix {\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z } $$

If rotation is about the *x*-axis, then use the first column of the matrix above and multiply it with $\omega_x$.